# Use server side includes to check if current page is the home page--if so, display script tag

Tags: javascript, sitecore, server-side-includes

I am working on a Sitecore site, and for the master file, I want to check to see if I am on the home page or not. If I am, then I want to display a script tag for an animation file's contents (Note: I can't really move the script to a different file--it has to be as it is)

I'm not too familiar with server side includes/statements, but I know it's possible to perform such a check with server side if statement:

```
 <!--#if is home page, then show the script tag -->
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/scripts/Subpages/Main-Image-2_edgePreload.js"></script>
 <!--#endif -->
```

I have no idea how I could perform the check, though....is there a way to check the page URL or page name or page ID?

Comment: This seems a little convoluted. Is the animation a separate component? Could this component register the script to load rather than having the page check to see if it the page it needs to load on?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out if the current page is the home by examining the value of the Start Item.

In your web.config you will have the StartItem which will point to the home node in your Sitecore instance.

```
<site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/"  startItem="/home" database="web" />
```

You can get access to this value by using this value in the Sitecore API

Sitecore.Context.Site.StartPath.

You can then use the GetItem command on this to resolve an item and compare this with the context item.

```
Item startItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Site.StartPath);

// check if page is home page
if(startItem.ID.Equals(Sitecore.Context.Item.ID))
{

}
```

This is also answered here:

[How to determine in sitecore whether given item is start item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037501/how-to-determine-in-sitecore-whether-given-item-is-start-item)